# Venn Diagram i R Studio

Tags: rstudio, venn-diagram

How do I make a Venn diagram that looks like this:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options. For instance, I created a library called nVennR which you can install from CRAN. For your example,

```
library(nVennR)
myV <- createVennObj(nSets = 5, sNames = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'))
myV <- setVennRegion(myV, c('E'), 2)
myV <- setVennRegion(myV, c('E', 'A'), 4)
myV <- setVennRegion(myV, c('B'), 8)
myV <- setVennRegion(myV, c('A', 'B'), 10)
myV <- setVennRegion(myV, c('A'), 9)
myV <- setVennRegion(myV, c('D', 'A'), 4)
myV <- setVennRegion(myV, c('D'), 8)
myV <- setVennRegion(myV, c('A', 'C'), 3)
myV <- setVennRegion(myV, c('C'), 5)
pV <- plotVenn(nVennObj = myV)
```

And the result is:

[image: Example Euler diagram]

The result is a vectorial image that can be saved and edited. For more details, you can read the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nVennR/vignettes/nVennR.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: When running your code we get the error message " Warning message:
In showSVG(myVenn, ...) :
  The figure cannot be rendered in the plot window. Please, use the arguments outFile and/or systemShow."     We have tried to set systemShow=T, but we don't know where to go from here.

Comment: This depends on which system you are using. I take it you do not have a graphical output. The safest option is to include 'outFile=path_to_svg_file', like pV <- plotVenn(nVennObj = myV, outFile='~/tmp.svg'), and then you get an svg file. You can open and edit that file with programs like Inkscape.